# How can I send funds from an EVM smart contract to a L1 address?

Tags: development, wasp, shimmerevm

I am trying to implement a smart contract to which users can send their funds and then these can be withdrawn to their L1 address.

I found and modified some testing code from the wasp repository (https://github.com/iotaledger/wasp/blob/develop/packages/evm/evmtest/ISCTest.sol):

```
function withdraw(L1Address memory receiver, uint64 amount) external {
        require(amount > 0, "Invalid amount to withdraw");
        require(balance >= amount, "User do not have the demanded balance");
        balance -= amount;
        
        ISCAssets memory assets;
        assets.baseTokens = amount;
        ISCSendMetadata memory metadata;
        ISCSendOptions memory options;
        ISC.sandbox.send(receiver, assets, true, metadata, options);
    }
```

I am trying to test this code but I have not been able to find an example which forms the `L1Address` structure. I had a look at some go code which serializes the address and its type but I don't fully understand how it is done. Right now I am calling the function from Remix IDE but the idea is to call it using python and Web3.py. So my question is:

*How can I send a valid address to this function?*

Also, if this is not possible or just a bit too complex,

*Can I use either the evm core contract or the wasp-cli to send my L2 funds to a L1 address? If so, how?*